# How to connect Vertica schema with vertica_python?

Tags: python, vertica, vertica-python

I try to connect to vertica DB with 2 schema: 'public' and 'my_schema'
I can only connect to 'public' schema and not to 'my_schema'

```
import vertica_python

conn_info = {'host': '****',
             'port': 5433,
             'user': '****',
             'password': '****',
             'database': 'my_schema',
             # 10 minutes timeout on queries
             'read_timeout': 600,
             # default throw error on invalid UTF-8 results
             'unicode_error': 'strict',
             # SSL is disabled by default
             'ssl': False}
conn = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

and this is what I get:

```
vertica_python.errors.ConnectionError: Severity: FATAL, Message: Database "my_schema" does not exist
```

how can I connect the 'my_schema' with python?

Comment: It has to be the database name, not schema name. I think you can check thay via meta-command `\l`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution,
`database` should be "public" and the query should be with the schema name:

```
select * from my_schema.{table name}
```

Comment: Seems to work. But, in Vertica, the database is the name of the database when the DBA created it. You also connect to the database , also in vertica_python, using: name or IP address of one Vertica node; Vertica database name; Vertica user id; Vertica user id's password. Within the database, tables are organised within schemas - which gives them a two-level naming: <schema_name> . <table_name> .